# How to launch specific activity from GooglePlayGames invitation

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I'm trying to create a new android application that is comprised of multiple mini-games.  The launcher activity extends BaseGameActivity and has a sign-in button and a ListView containing all the possible games that can be played.

Inside of a mini-game activity (also extends BaseGameActivity), how can I get it to create a notification which will launch a specific Activity?  Currently, when I call invitePlayersToGame, the invitation that gets sent is for the full application (Mini-Games) and not the individual game (specific dice game).

```
public void invitePlayersToGame(View pView) {
    Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(getApiClient(), 1, 1);
    intent.putExtra("gameName", "Patman Yahtzee");
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
}
```

Is there a way to get the notification to generate with a specific message?  Is there a way to get notification to open directly to the mini-game activity without going to the main launcher activity first?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to figure this one for my game too. Will update this if I find something. Interesting that there is no documentation on this anywhere even though the Games doc from Google specifically says that when responding to an invite the user should be taken directly to the game activity rather than the menu. Which would mean there is a way to force a specific activity to start.

Comment: I think you would possibly need to create a different game for each minigame in the Google Play developers console

Answer (score 0):

You can send [sendReliableMessage](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer.html#sendReliableMessage(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMultiplayer.ReliableMessageSentCallback,%20byte[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for method handshaking.

First enter a room (quickgame or send invite).

```
public void openInvitationIntent() {
    // launch the player selection screen
    // minimum: 1 other player; maximum: 1 other players
    Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
}
```

onConnected:

```
   @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // QuickGame
    if (mGameMode == 1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected() called. Sign in successful!");
        Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in succeeded.");
        startQuickGame();

        // register listener so we are notified if we receive an invitation to play
        // while we are in the game
        if (connectionHint != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: connection hint provided. Checking for invite.");
            Invitation inv = connectionHint.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);
            if (inv != null && inv.getInvitationId() != null) {
                // retrieve and cache the invitation ID
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: connection hint has a room invite!");
                acceptInviteToRoom(inv.getInvitationId());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // Send request
    else if (mGameMode == 0) {
        // request code for the "select players" UI
        // can be any number as long as it's unique
        invitationInbox();
    }
    // request accepted
    else {
        mIncomingInvitationId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(AppConstants.RC_INVITATION_ID);
        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(mIncomingInvitationId);
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfigBuilder.build());

        // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

After this, you can send model class (includes what you need).

```
 private void broadcastMessage(ModelGameRecievedMessage broadcastedMessage, boolean isFinal) {
    try {
        if ( mParticipants != null && broadcastedMessage != null) {
            byte[] bytes = Utils.serialize(broadcastedMessage);
            // Send to every other participant.
            for (Participant p : mParticipants) {
                if (p.getParticipantId().equals(mMyId)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (p.getStatus() != Participant.STATUS_JOINED) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (mRoomId != null) {
                    if (isFinal) {
                        // final score notification must be sent via reliable broadcastedMessage
                        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage(mGoogleApiClient, null, bytes,
                                mRoomId, p.getParticipantId());
                    } else {
                        // it's an interim score notification, so we can use unreliable
                        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendUnreliableMessage(mGoogleApiClient, bytes,
                                mRoomId, p.getParticipantId());
                    }
                }
            }
            Logy.l("broadcastedMessage.getMessageTypeId(); " + broadcastedMessage.getMessageTypeId());
            Logy.l("broadcastedMessage.getMessage(); " + broadcastedMessage.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

finally you can reach the data on other devices:

```
 @Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage rtm) {

    byte[] bufy = rtm.getMessageData();
    ModelGameRecievedMessage recievedMessage = null;
    try {
        recievedMessage = (ModelGameRecievedMessage) Utils.deserialize(bufy);
        Logy.l("recievedMessage.getMessageTypeId(); " + recievedMessage.getMessageTypeId());
        Logy.l("recievedMessage.getMessage(); " + recievedMessage.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logy.e("Exception onRealTimeMessageReceived deserialize:  " + e);
    }
    switch (recievedMessage.getMessageTypeId()) {
        case AppConstants.RC_MULTI_START_TIMEMILIS_MULTIPLAYER:
   ....
```